# How to get a single object from list of object

Tags: c#, mongodb

Please can you tell me how to get a single data object in this method.
It's difficult for me , because of returning type. I'm trying to get a single data from my MongoDB collection, and then use that that on different form to show who is active. My error is always in definition of returning type.

This is my code:

```
 public var PrijavljenKorisnik(ModelPrijavaKorisnika  prvKor)
    {
        MongoCollection<ModelKorisici> kljenti = GetTasksCollection();
        List<ModelKorisici> DohvaceniKorisnik = new List<ModelKorisici>();
        var upit = from lambda in kljenti.AsQueryable<ModelKorisici >()
                   where lambda.kor_ime  == prvKor.PrijavaKor && lambda.uloga == "korisnik"
                   select lambda;


        foreach (var dohvaceni in upit)
        {
            DohvaceniKorisnik.Add(dohvaceni);
            if (DohvaceniKorisnik.Count() >= 1 && dohvaceni.uloga == "korisnik")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ovaj korinik je prijavljen kao korisnik");
                frmKorisnik fmk = new frmKorisnik();
                fmk.Show();
                frmPrijavaForma frmPriv = new frmPrijavaForma();
                frmPriv.Close();
                return dohvaceni;
            }
            else
            {
                DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Potrebno se je predhodno registrirati u aplikaciju KnjigoLjubac");
                if (d == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    frmRegistracijaForma frmReg = new frmRegistracijaForma();
                    frmReg.Show();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `public var` should probably be `public ModelKorisici`...?

Comment: why cant you change the return type to nullable type of "dohvaceni" ?

Comment: i tried with ModelKorisici, but there is still an error on definition of method

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @MichaelEarls DohvaceniKorisnik is a `List<ModelKorisici>()`, so Add should take a ModelKorisici.

Comment: not all code path return a value, sorry i am new in c# and in OO prgramming

Comment: butt then i can't use a method add, to put in a list for counting a objects in list

Comment: @MatijaDomjan If you want to put the results of your LINQ in a list, surround your LINQ in parenthesis and add `.ToList();` to it. You can also simply use the `.Count()` method, or use `.FirstOrDefault()` and check if it's null (if it's null, there were no results, if not, then `FirstOrDefault()` will return...the first item. You can then call `ToList()` on that if you want to use it as a List.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your intent is, but I'll take a stab at it. You suggested that you're looking for a single value, so I thought this might work for you:

```
var dohvaceni = (from lambda in kljenti.AsQueryable<ModelKorisici >()
               where lambda.kor_ime  == prvKor.PrijavaKor && lambda.uloga == "korisnik"
               select lambda)
            .FirstOrDefault();

if (dohvaceni != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ovaj korinik je prijavljen kao korisnik");
    // the rest of the code for a match...
}
else
{
    DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Potrebno se je predhodno registrirati u aplikaciju KnjigoLjubac");
    // the rest of the code for no matches...
}
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: My intent is to get a data from mongodb , and return it , that i can use the the datas in some another form. This is a code for login form, and i need to get username of registered user. So , i tried to return a whole object, and then used it on another form.

Comment: I ran some of your variable names through Google translate and I see that you're using a column name uloga (Role) to determine if they are in the "korisnik" (user) role and if you have a match with the kor_ime (user name). Since you're new to this, I would recommend creating a constructor on your form that would take an instance of your user class and then create your form with that constructor (example: MyForm myForm = new MyForm(userInstance)). Ideally, you'd look into implementing a Custom principal and IIdentity so you could use the built in .NET security.

Comment: frmRegistracijaForma formReg = new frmRegistracijaForma();
ModelPrijavaKorisnika prvKor = new ModelPrijavaKorisnika();
KorisniciBazaPodataka bpk = new KorisniciBazaPodataka();label1.Text = bpk.PrijavljenKorisnik(prvKor).ToString();                                                      i tried this...but now i have a null reference exception